# Options for 301 redirect from blogger

Tags: seo, http-status-code-301, blogger

I can't use .htaccess on Blogger, but I need to try to keep the search rankings for posts.

Users can redirect fine (using Javascript), but if I can't use a proper 301 redirect, how can I ensure Google doesn't have a fit and drop the rankings for the posts?

Comment: By way of not really answering your question, you might try Wordpress instead of Blogger.  It gives you a lot more flexibility to do those sorts of things because you can run the software on your own server where you're in full control.

Comment: I know, for future ones I would, however this is a currently running Blogger site that I'm trying to migrate.

Comment: See my answer here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/14243/8507

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like canonical urls will accomplish as close as possible to what I want:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html 
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this post.

edit;
[gist.github.com/9ee54b15a3a7627e9f6b](http://gist.github.com/9ee54b15a3a7627e9f6b) was what was pasted into the Blogger template. The index/reverse[_g] functions just 301'd to the correct post.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new built-in option now, in "Settings - Search preferences"

[image: screenshot]

Edit: Actually it works for redirecting within the blog only, sorry. But I think the answer is worth being here, in case someone needs it (this question ranks in google for "redirect blogger page".

Comment: I tried this option, specifying my blogger url in From address and my website url in To address. But i see that, when i open my blogger site, it initially loads all the home page, and then starts redirecting to my website.

Answer (score 1):

`<meta>` refreshes don't work, and `Rel=canonical` DOES pass link juice, even cross-domain, so use that method instead. [SEO MOZ has a great article and video describing](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/cross-domain-canonical-the-new-301-whiteboard-friday) the specific experiment that seems to prove that cross-domain canonicals do work. I don't have enough credits to downvote the META Refresh response, but that's absolutely wrong, and [Google explicitly tells Webmasters not to use META refresh for redirects](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2721217).

Comment: Actually, meta refresh worked for me, in fact, it worked much better than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest canonicalization of your URLs. Though search engines will treat this better than no action at all (i.e., duplicate content), it will not transfer your "link juice" and all your SEO signals. Supposedly, a meta refresh tag will be treated by search engines just like a 301 redirect via htaccess.

They are real easy to do in Blogger.

Open the template, click **Edit HTML** then click **Proceed**. Find the line that says:

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
```

Right underneath that, add the following:

```
<meta content="0;url=http://YOUR NEW URL HERE" http-equiv="refresh"/>
```

Enter your url where it says "YOUR NEW URL HERE." This will be better for SEO purposes than mere canonical URLs (though it isn't AS good as a permanent redirect via the .htaccess file).

Comment: Instead of putting your website in an answer, add it to your profile.

Comment: Do you have a source for "Supposedly, a meta refresh tag will ..."?

Answer (score 0):

If your blog has its own domain name, then

- On Blogger, unlink your domain from the blog
- On the DNS configuration, redirect your domain to another host
- create the .htaccess file with all the redirections