# 301 direct from blogger blog

Tags: wordpress, redirect, blogger

I have changed to my own hosted wordpress blog from a blogspot blog and now I wan't to make a 301 redirect from my blogspot blog to my wordpress blog. I havent used the "Blogger importer tool" to import the blog because that just gave me problems. So I know that I cant redirect to the individual pages on my blog. **All I want is to redirect any of my pages from my blogspot blog to the frontpage of my wordpress blog.** I just can't figure out how to do it. But I know it can be done through the template design.

I hope you can help.

Old blog: www.secret-invizimals.blogspot.com/
New blog: www.secretsection.com/invizimals/

BR

Comment: possible duplicate of [Options for 301 redirect from blogger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798259/options-for-301-redirect-from-blogger)

Comment: No they don't do the work. The first link in the answer is for the same domain only and the second needs access to the .htaccess file (or what it was called)

Comment: Yes, they will work. The Canonical URL `meta` tag now supports cross-domain canonical URLs.

Comment: Shall the page redirect or is it only so that Google knows that it has changed. Because what I understood was that the page should redirect the user. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Do a meta refresh for the user-side of things. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">`, or do it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer in the comments :D